# finding the owner manual for old vehicles

Tags: service-manual

We bought an Mercedes Vaneo for my disabled brother because is an already made accessible model. The problem is that the manuals are in German language and I can't find the English version. Is true that the car is from  2004 and this model isn't produced since [2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes-Benz_Vaneo).

Do you have any advice for me about where to find the English version of this car manuals? It is a Mercedez Benz Vaneo 1.7 CDI Ambiente... I'm looking for owners manual

Any feedback is appreciated! :)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Maybe Bosch has something in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a manual specifically for the Vaneo, but given that it is based on the first-gen A-Class the corresponding Haynes manual should do the trick for most common jobs. They actually state explicitly that it "also covers major mechanical features of Vaneo". I hope that is adequate for your case.

https://haynes.com/en-gb/mercedes-benz-class-petrol-diesel-98-04-haynes-repair-manual

Comment: Ha - I posted as a comment a link to the same manual... it was removed so you are lucky...

Comment: @SolarMike: there was a link to a google drive document, but the link contained an executable with a virus. Maybe this is the reason for the deletion

Comment: [edit: rda already answered]   I tried your link before answering but it led me to a sub-1MB .zip file that was probably a virus/malware - chrome wouldn't even let me complete the download. 

The reason your comment was removed probably had to do with me flagging it. I didn't mean any offense as I wasn't judging your intent, it's just that I deemed it to be dangerous.

I'd like to point out that there are actually several such vehicle manual "downloads" that try to get you to either pay for copied material, or download files that are potentially dangerous.

Comment: Ok thanks and understood, I was at work so the link would not work for me anyway, but I was hoping the OP would be able to complete a search...